# Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object after upgrade

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, upgrade, ce-1.8.0.0

We tried to upgrade our Magento installation from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.0.0. Now we got the following error on all pages:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in /home/clientname/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 165
```

We tried to clear all caches, disable and recompile the compiler and reindex the indexer. Earlier today everything went well on our local installation. This is the same installation except some orders and client data.

When the compiler is enabled the error changes in:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in /home/clientname/domains/domain.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 17761
```

How we can debug this error?

Comment: I too upgraded to 1.8 magento
Mine has some same problem but the error i am getting is not in the varien...see the error as below: > Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductAttribute() on a
> non-object in
> /home/shopk3if/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
> on line 50 plz help me for the code as I'm not the developer...

Comment: Are you sure that you have compilation turned off?

Comment: @MichaelvanEijden Were you able to track down the root cause of this?

Comment: @AlanStorm For some reason, there was only a part of the files transfered during the upgrade. Your answer brought me to the right place though. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue..... but I now tried to overwrite all files with the contents of the magento ZIP installation archive.... but it didn´t help. That´s going to become a loooong debug session! NO update of Magento up to now worked for me without problems!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at line 165

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
$this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();
```

The method `_getRequestRewriteController` should return an object.  For some reason, it's not returning an object in your system.

Taking a look at that method definition, we see the following

```
protected function _getRequestRewriteController()
{
    $className = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/request_rewrite/model');

    return Mage::getSingleton('core/factory')->getModel($className, array(
        'routers' => $this->getRouters(),
    ));
}
```

Mage looks at the `global/request_rewrite/model` configuration node to find a class alias.  In a store system this should be

```
core/url_rewrite_request
```

Which Magento then uses to instantiate a model.  My two guesses are

1. There's a module with a different, invalid class name here, which prevents Magento from instantiating the object.
2. Your system is missing the `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` class file (at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite/Request.php`), which is new in Magento 1.8

Comment: Also, see the answer/comments from @navotjer below.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and beside clearing the cache, I had to set folder permissions on /var and subdirectories to 777 (don't worry, the .htaccess file in /var prevents everything to be "human" readable).

Comment: Ran into this today and seconding this answer — untaring a new Magento codebase can change the permissions on your `var` folder, which means Magneto may revert to a system var folder that has an old cached configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a cache server like memcached try to restart it as well. I had the same issue and I resolved this way.

Comment: Or if Redis: `redis-cli flushall`

Answer (score 2):

I tried to follow the explanation by @AlanStorm, but ultimately found it was a caching issue. I just had to `rm -rf *` all the files in `~/public_html/var/cache` and I found that the site loaded correctly.

Comment: Simple like this. I had the same problem when upgrading from 1.7 to 1.9, but forgot to clear cache folder.

Answer (score 2):

Clear redis cache;

> redis-cli

```
FLUSHALL
```

Its solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in /home/clientname/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 165
```

Deleting all in /var/cache solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything in var/cache solved the problem for me as well.

Also had to delete the maintenance.flag file before this problem occurred, as a maintenance page was present.