# uploaded a module then got an error "Call to a member function rewrite()"

Tags: module

i just upload a module then got an error

Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in /var/www/directory/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 165

i completely removed the module but the error still exists, how can i retrieve my website.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?  You can manually do this by deleting the contents of the `var/cache/` directory.

Comment: problem fixed because i had changed the permission of folder var, thanks all answers.

Comment: Try to put this as an answer and free feel to accept it or accept @alanstorm answer. Please don't leave a question as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the module's old configuration is still in your cache.  This is a common problem when removing modules.  Try clearing your Magento cache.  If that doesn't help, there's more information on debugging the problem in [this other question thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-rewrite-on-a-non-object-after-upgrade/8643#8643)